# Can wordpress differentiate between added and updated posts?

Tags: posts, date

I've been looking trying to find an answer as to wether it is possible to get wordpress to display if a post has just been **added**(**published**) or if it was simply **updated**?

(This is to add on a homepage, to differentiate between a new post and one that was updated.)

Comment: Comparing `post_date` vs `post_modified` can be an option

Comment: you could post that as the answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

[get_post_modified_time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_modified_time) : Retrieves the time at which the post was last modified.